# Prism version 7 release notes (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Somebody knows the changes in 7.xxx versions of prism?

I'm trying to use **prism** for implementing **MVVM pattern in a new XamarinForms** application. 
This  new application has an android version restriction. Will be used in a tablet that only supports Andriod 6.0 (API 25).

If I add Prism version > than 7,THEN I get a problem because prism in this versions uses Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.5.0.122203).

Now, If I follow this PRISM version dependency I must to target an Android grather than 7.  Because according this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.5/2.5.0-stable/) Xamarin Forms in versions greather than 2.5 work with Android > 7

So, at the end. I need to know what I would not have if I use Prism 6.3.

Comment: [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.5/2.5.0-stable/) is the restriction that would made me use Android version higher than 7.0

Comment: Can you clarify why are you not able to target a new SDK? A link in a comment to the Xamarin Forms release notes without explanation as to your issue doesn't help anyone answer your question. Please update and clarify your question.

Comment: you can have the above specified config, and still target devices with Android 6. you upgrade to support higher versions, and not to stop supporting lower ones, Backward Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prism 7 and Xamarin.Forms 3 to make an app for Android 6 without problems (my latest app support Android 4.4.2, using prism 7 and Xamarin.Forms 2.5).

For every Android project you have:

**Target Framework** - specifies which framework to use in building your application. This API level is used at compile time by Xamarin.Android.

**Minimum Android Version** - Specifies the oldest Android version that you want your app to support. This API level is used at run time by Android.

**Target Android Version** - Specifies the version of Android that your app is intended to run on. This API level is used at run time by Android.

So you can use Prism 7 with the latest version of Xamarin.Forms, target the latest SDK in the target Framework settings, and then specify your desidered API version in Minimum Android Version and Target Android Version.